# ABBYY Mobile + MONO

Tags: mono, abbyy

I'm an student and I'm trying to develop a reader for low vision users using OCR utilities.
I'm debating to use MONO because I'm familiar with c#. 
Is it possible to combine ABBYY mobile in a MONO project(Android or IOS)?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

No, it would be extremely slow.